# Android Room library taking Transaction as keyword instead of sql table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I have a table named "Transaction". While writing the query room is taking Transaction as keyword and giving an error. I want room to consider Transaction as table now as a keyword.

How can i achieve this?

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Using **[Transaction]**.* worked.

```
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH)
    @Query("SELECT RetailTransaction.*, [Transaction].*, SaleReturnLineItem.*, PriceModificationLineItem.* FROM RetailTransaction " +
            "INNER JOIN [Transaction] ON [Transaction].transactionID = 
    public abstract List<RetailTransactionGenerator> getRetailTransactions();
```